# The convergence of a power series (Radius of Convergence)

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of the following power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n z^{n(n+1)}}{n}$$

Here's my working
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|  \frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^{(n+1)(n+2)}}{n+1} \frac{n}{(-1)^nz^{n(n+1)}}|$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\big|  \frac{(-1)^n(-1) z^{(n^2+3n+2)}}{n+1} \frac{n}{(-1)^nz^{n^2}z^n}\big|$$
$$= \lim_{n\to \infty}\big|  \frac{ -z^{3n}z^2}{n+1} \frac{n}{{}z^n}\big|$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\big|  \frac{ -nz^{2n}z^2}{n+1}\big|$$
I am stuck after this. Is the limit greater than 1 since anything raised to the power infinity is very huge? How do I do this? Also what happens if z=i?

Answer (score 3):

As so often straightforward comparisons will give the result.

The series $\sum z^n$ has radius of convergence $1$. The series $\sum (n+1)$ diverges.

(a) For $|z|<1$ we have that
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}\right|\leqslant |z|^n$$
so by the Comparison Test our series converges for $|z|<1$ and so $R\geqslant 1$.

(b) For any $a>0$ we have that
$$
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(1+a)^{n(n+1)}\right|\geqslant\frac{1+n(n+1)a}{n}\geqslant (n+1)a
$$
and so by the Comparison Test our series diverges at $1+a$, and so $R\leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{-nz^{2n+2}}{n+1}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}|z|^{2n+2}=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }|z|<1\\1&\text{ if }|z|=1\\\infty&\text{ if }|z|>1.\end{cases}$$So, your series converges if $|z|<1$ and diverges if $|z|>1$. Therefore, its radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do the following to see your series as a "usual" power series:

$$\frac{(-1)^n z^{n(n+1)}}n=a_mz^m\;,\;\;\text{when}\;\;a_m=\begin{cases}0,&m\neq2,6,12,...,k(k+1)\\{}\\\cfrac{(-1)^m}m,&m=k(k+1)\end{cases}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N$$

From here, using Cauchy-Hadamard theorem:

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]n}=1$$

so $\;R=1\;$ .

It's important to note that the series could be *not* considered a power series per dry definition (depending on the author), but it is possible to turn it into one as above.

Comment: Please do not use the same variable twice, set $m=n(n+1)$, or $n=m(m+1)$.

Comment: This is now over-corrected. The coefficient for the degree $m=n(n+1)$ is $a_m=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. One could solve $m+\frac14=(n+\frac12)^2\implies n=\sqrt{m+\frac14}-\frac12$.

Comment: @I've no idea what you'rse saying: the coefficient $\;a_m\;$ is defined in terms of $\;m\;$ which, is defined in terms of $\;n\;$ . What isn't clear? The coefficient for the degree $\;m\;$ is $\;a_m\;$ , which is defined there for every case of (natrual, of course) $\;m\;$ .Probably could be cleare to define it as function of $\;k\;$ and not $\;n\;$ itself...but I think it's sufficiently clear now

Comment: The coefficient for the term with degree $m=n(n+1)$, that is, for the term $a_mz^m=a_{n(n+1)}z^{n(n+1)}$ is $a_m=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. This does not change the overall result, as $|a_m|\sim \frac1{\sqrt{m}}$ also gives radius of convergence equal to one, but in the detail your formula is wrong.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Again, you're focusing in indexes.: what you say at the beginning of your last comment is *exactly* what I wrote from the beginning (repeating the index $\;n\;$ , which I corrected). The formula (CH) is correct, whether you use $\;n,m, t\;$ or any other natural index.

Comment: No, you claim in your first formula that the monomial $z^{n(n+1)}$ is identical to the monomial $z^n$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: the expression for $a_m$ in your answer is not quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

The series in the posting can be expressed as
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} z^{n(n+1)}=\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_mz^m$$

where $a_m=0$ unless $m\in\{n(n+1):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, in which case $a_m=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, where $n=\sqrt{m+\frac14}-\frac12$.

Then by the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) criteria, the series converges for all $z$ with $|z|<R$ and diverges for all $|z|>R$, where
$$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_m\sqrt[m]{|a_m|}=\lim_m\frac{1}{\Big(\sqrt{m+\frac14}-\frac12\Big)^{1/m}}=1$$
As can be seen from the fact that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[k]{k}=1$.